# Finding rows using foreign keys between 2 pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes which are related to each other with a foreign key. I'm trying to find rows in the first dataframe where the Fk appears in the second dataframe.

Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    'b': ['5', '6', '7', '8'],
    'c': ['3', '4', '5', '6']
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'd': ['1', '2', '4', '3', '5', '6'],
    'e': ['4', '3', '2', '1', '5', '6'],
    'f': ['7', '4', '6', '5', '8', '3']
})
key1 = ['a', 'c']
key2 = ['d', 'f']
mask = (df1[key1].isin(df2[key2])).all(axis=1)
```

I'm expecting mask to be

```
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

But what I'm getting is

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

This is a simplified example. The datasets and keys are dynamic so I can't just hard-code some filters. How can I go about getting the correct indexes in the mask?

Comment: Are you sure you have True at index 1?

Comment: You're right, I've updated the output in the question

Comment: Are you sure you need False at index 2?

Comment: You're right too, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform your columns into `tuple` to group columns before applying `isin`:

```
>>> df1[key1].apply(tuple, axis=1).isin(df2[key2].apply(tuple, axis=1))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame.isin` against another DataFrame expects the indexes *and* columns to match so you don't get the desired output. One way is to tuplify your values along rows and then use `Series.isin`:

```
>>> d1, d2 = df1[key1], df2[key2]
>>> d1.agg(tuple, axis=1).isin(d2.agg(tuple, axis=1))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: `agg` is a 3 times slower than `apply`